# How to solve CORS Policy problem in Vue production build?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, mapbox

I developing `Vue.js` app using *Vue-CLI* and it's *dev-server*. In my project I use theme with Google's fonts and MapBox. In dev-server all works right. But when I built production version and deploy it on nginx, I start to get CORS Policy errors while loading fonts and map's items.

> Access to font at https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v20/KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBBc4.woff2' from origin `http://myapp.example.com` has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-compress is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
>
> Access to fetch at 'https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.mapbox-streets-v8/9/313/157.vector.pbf?sku=101vNL909uOWx&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibW9yZmFpciIsImEiOiJjank3YmVxMnYwMW54M2lueXAzcm8xeW52In0.VM_5oG33ipJluIIfMUiN5A' from origin 'http://myapp.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`

Comment: Why don't you download the fonts you need and add them to the project ?

Comment: This is Vuetify and MapBox issues.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25260259/3233827

Comment: ssc-hrep3, sorry, but I dont see solution ib ur link..

Answer (score 1):

This was the bug Chrome 76 and FriGate extention.